# Powershell Runbook [Invoke-ASCmd], FileNotFoundException for xmla file

Tags: azure, powershell, ssas, azure-runbook

I'm trying to make a script that creates automatic partions for SSAS via Powershell Runbook, but whenever I try to read in the xmla file i get the following error:
[image]

[image]

My code that calls this is as followed:

```
$StorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName

$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $StorageAccount.Context -Container "Database name" -Blob "CreateNewPartition.xmla"

$file = $blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()
Invoke-ASCmd `
    -Database $AnalysisServiceDatabase `
    -InputFile $file `
    -server $AnalysisServiceServer
```

When using the following code:

```
$memStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadToStream($memStream)
$readStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($memStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
$memStream.Position = 0
$file = ($readStream.ReadToEnd() -replace "`0",'' | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

I get this error: 
[image]

And when trying this code:

```
$byteArray = New-Object Byte[] $blob.Length
$file = $blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadToByteArray($byteArray, 0)
```

I get this error: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix.

In the first example, you are correctly reading the contents of the file from the blob. But, `-InputFile` is expecting a file path (e.g. `C:\arst.xmla`), and can't handle the raw *contents* of the `.xmla` file.

Instead, use the `-Query` parameter to pass the contents of the file to `Invoke-ASCmd` e.g.:

```
...

$query = $blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()
Invoke-ASCmd `
    -Database $AnalysisServiceDatabase `
    -Query $query `
    -server $AnalysisServiceServer
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks :)